# Adding "$location" in controller dependencies array stops ng-click from working

Tags: angularjs

I have a button with a ng-click call that worked before I injected "$location" in my controller array of dependencies. The function 'goToGetLocation()' is called at the very top of petType.html, and the function is defined at the bottom of the controller. You can see here that none of my buttons are calling any functions: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/petType

Controller for petType.html:

```
.controller('PetCtrl',["$location", function ($scope, $log, $location) {
    $scope.title1 = 'Button';
    $scope.title4 = 'Warn';
    $scope.isDisabled = true;


    $scope.activeMenu = '';

    var speed;

    $scope.setSpeed = function () {
        if ($scope.activeMenu == 'fast') {
            speed = 46;
            //alert(speed);
        }

        if ($scope.activeMenu == 'medFast') {
            speed = 35;
        }

        if ($scope.activeMenu == 'medium') {
            speed = 30;
        }

        if ($scope.activeMenu == 'medSlow') {
            speed = 23;
        }

        if ($scope.activeMenu == 'slow') {
            speed = 12;
        }

        $log.debug(speed);
        return speed;
    }

    function goToGetLocation() {
        $location.url($location.path() + "/" + speed + "/getLocation" );
        location.reload();
    }
}]);
```

petType.html:

```
<md-button ng-disabled="setSpeed() == null" ng-click="goToGetLocation()" sticky class="md-raised md-primary">Next</md-button>

<h2></h2>

<h2>Choose the pet type that best matches your pet</h2>

<div style="text-align: center">

    <button  style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block; margin: auto" class="button" 
    ng-class="{active : activeMenu === 'fast'}" ng-click="activeMenu = 'fast'; setSpeed();">
        <img height="220px" width="220px" src="images/greyhound.png" />
   </button>
    <h4>Fast (Avg Speed: 46km/h)</h4>
    <p>Includes dogs such as Greyhounds and German Shepherds</p>
    <br> <br>

    <button style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block; margin: auto" class="button" 
    ng-class="{active : activeMenu === 'medFast'}" ng-click="activeMenu = 'medFast'; setSpeed()">
    <img height="220px" width="220px" src="images/greatDane.png" />
   </button>
    <h4>Medium/Fast (Avg Speed: 35km/h)</h4>
    <p>Includes dogs such as Great Danes and Pitbulls</p>
    <br> <br>

    <button style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block; margin: auto" class="button" 
    ng-class="{active : activeMenu === 'med'}" ng-click="activeMenu = 'med'; setSpeed()">
    <img style="padding-right: 25px" height="220px" width="220px" src="images/husky.png" />
   </button>
    <h4>Medium (Avg Speed: 30km/h)</h4>
    <p>Includes dogs such as Giant Schnauzers and Siberian Huskies</p>
    <br> <br>

    <button style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block; margin: auto" class="button" 
    ng-class="{active : activeMenu === 'medSlow'}" ng-click="activeMenu = 'medSlow'; setSpeed()">
    <img height="220px" width="220px" src="images/golden.png" />
   </button>
    <h4>Medium/Slow (Avg Speed: 23km/h)</h4>
    <p>Includes dogs such as Golden Retrievers and Dachshunds</p>
    <br> <br>

    <button style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block; margin: auto" class="button" 
    ng-class="{active : activeMenu === 'slow'}" ng-click="activeMenu = 'slow'; setSpeed()">
    <img style="padding-left: 25px" height="220px" width="220px" src="images/cat.png" />
   </button>
    <h4>Slow (Avg Speed: 12km/h)</h4>
    <p>Includes cast as well as dogs such as Basset Hounds and Bulldogs</p>
    <br> <br>
</div>
```

I have a very similar controller and view that IS working:

view: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/100/getLocation

Controller:

```
.controller('MapsCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$interval", "$state", "$stateParams",
      function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $interval, $state, $stateParams) {
          $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;
          var center = { latitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lat), longitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lon) };
          //alert(JSON.stringify(center));
          Object.freeze(center); //caused TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ('latitude') ...

          console.log($stateParams);

          $scope.map = {
              center: center,
              pan: false,
              zoom: 16,
              refresh: false,
              events: {},
              bounds: {}
          };

          $scope.map.circle = {
              id: 1,
              center: center,
              radius: 500, //(current time - date lost)*km/hour
              stroke: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  weight: 2,
                  opacity: 1
              },

              fill: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  opacity: 0.5
              },
              geodesic: false, // optional: defaults to false
              draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              clickable: true, // optional: defaults to true
              editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
              events: {
                  dblclick: function () {
                      $log.debug("circle dblclick");
                  },
                  radius_changed: function (gObject) {
                      var radius = gObject.getRadius();
                      $log.debug("circle radius radius_changed " + radius);
                  }
              }
          }

          //Increase Radius:
          $interval(function () {
              $scope.map.circle.radius += parseFloat($stateParams.speed); //dynamic var
          }, 1000); //end of interval function


      } ]) //end of controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependency array is incomplete. It should have as many string params as function arguments and in same order

Change

```
.controller('PetCtrl',["$location", function ($scope, $log, $location) {
```

To

```
.controller('PetCtrl',["$scope", "$log", "$location", function ($scope, $log, $location) {
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. The function that allows 'next' to be clicked is called, but the function called upon clicking that button (at the bottom of the controller) that should change the web page is still not called.

Comment: is `speed` defined when you call it? Do you have a route change error handler? Not enough known to debug that one

Comment: I have updated the question with a controller and view that is working and similar to my current problem. I think speed is defined or else it would return an error. And I don't have a route change error handler but I don't think I need one do I?

Comment: if using a router you should...would tell you why it's not working. Writing for only working conditions is easy...have to account for errors and be able to debug them

Comment: Ok any advice or resources for learning how to do that? Or just google 'route change error handler' ?

Comment: read the router docs... google is a fast way to find it also though

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm using ui.router so should i stay strictly on those docs, or would the router docs be good too?

Comment: yes...will be `$stateChangeError` event. Should also use `$state.go()` for switching

Answer (score 0):

You must define the args of the controller function with the same number and order of injections.

try this:

```
.controller('PetCtrl',["$scope", "$log", "$location", function ($scope, $log, $location) {
```

Best regards,

Bernardo Baumblatt